# Lubuntu 20.04 video streaming: colours too pale

Tags: lubuntu, google-chrome, vlc, colors, color-management

Live streams of tv stations are paler than the actual tv programme. This seems to hold true for streaming in browsers (Firefox and Google Chrome) as well as VLC streams.

I have Lubuntu 20.04 (lxqt desktop)

I saw some comments in the internet, one even indicating a bug somewhere (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/chrome-chromium-desaturated-colors/17432). However the workaround mentioned on that page to go to "settings->colour = OFF" seems not available.

Then I read something about colormgr tampering with colord. That looked like the right direction, but also awfully complicated as I seem to have to specify a profile file. Didn't find tutorials or howtos.

Boiling it down to the actual question: How can I increase the colour saturation on the screen?

Thanks for any hint or help.

Comment: Posting as a comment because I don't know if it will solve your issue, but you could try the `xgamma` command.  See `man xgamma` for options.

Comment: Thanks, will try. Also looked at xcalib. Seems similar.